# Exporting A PHP Different Dynamic Tables to EXCEL/SPREADSHEET horizontally

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the *php2excel* I found at https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel

Here is the output image

[image: enter image description]

THIS IS THE OUTPUT THAT I WANT

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js"></script>

          <script>
                          function printReports() {   
                              $(".center").table2excel({
                                exclude: ".noExl",
                                name: "Excel Document Name",
                                filename: "Term_Grades" + new Date().toISOString().replace(/[\-\:\.]/g, ""),
                                fileext: ".xlsx",
                                exclude_img: true,
                                exclude_links: true,
                                exclude_inputs: true
                              });
                            };
                          </script>
```

Download

```
                              <table border='0' class="table" style="border-color: white;float:left; width:18%">
                                <thead >
                                  <!-- <th>#</th> -->
                                  <th style= "background-color: #008066; color: white; height:60px; width: 28px; font-size:12px">No</th>
                                  <th style= "background-color: #008066; color: white; height:60px; width: 115px; font-size:12px">Lastname</th>   
                                  <th style= "background-color: #008066; color: white; height:60px; width: 42px; font-size:12px">SN</th>
                                  <th style= "background-color: #008066; color: white; height:60px; width: 100px; font-size:12px">COY</th>  
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                  <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td>3</td>
                                    <td>4</td>
                                  <tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>5</td>
                                    <td>6</td>
                                    <td>7</td>
                                    <td>8</td>
                                  <tr>



                                </tbody>
                              </table>



                              <table border='0' class="table" style="border-color: white;float:left; width:18%">
                                <thead >
                                  <!-- <th>#</th> -->
                                  <th style= "background-color: #008066; color: white; height:60px; width: 28px; font-size:12px">Another No</th>
                                  <th style= "background-color: #008066; color: white; height:60px; width: 115px; font-size:12px">Another Lastname</th>   
                                  <th style= "background-color: #008066; color: white; height:60px; width: 42px; font-size:12px">Another SN</th>
                                  <th style= "background-color: #008066; color: white; height:60px; width: 100px; font-size:12px">Another COY</th>  
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                  <tr>
                                    <td>Another 1</td>
                                    <td>Another 2</td>
                                    <td>Another 3</td>
                                    <td>Another 4</td>
                                  <tr>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>Another 5</td>
                                    <td>Another 6</td>
                                    <td>Another 7</td>
                                    <td>Another 8</td>
                                  <tr>



                                </tbody>
                              </table>

                              <table border='0' class="table" style="border-color: white;float:left; width:18%">
                                <thead >
                                  <!-- <th>#</th> -->
                                  <th style= "background-color: #008066; color: white; height:60px; width: 28px; font-size:12px">Some No</th>
                                  <th style= "background-color: #008066; color: white; height:60px; width: 115px; font-size:12px">Some Lastname</th>   
                                  <th style= "background-color: #008066; color: white; height:60px; width: 42px; font-size:12px">Some SN</th>
                                  <th style= "background-color: #008066; color: white; height:60px; width: 100px; font-size:12px">Some COY</th>  
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                  <tr>
                                    <td>Some 1</td>
                                    <td>Some 2</td>
                                    <td>Some 3</td>
                                    <td>Some 4</td>
                                  <tr>

                                  <tr>
                                    <td>Some 5</td>
                                    <td>Some 6</td>
                                    <td>Some 7</td>
                                    <td>Some 8</td>
                                  <tr>


                                </tbody>
                              </table>

                          </div>
```

The output of excel file when i export it is that the 2 tables are in the bottom instead of having side by side to each other. I cannot join 3 tables into 1 due to other instances so. The code above is just a dummy table

Comment: https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel i use this

Comment: Hi ! Welcome to Stackoverflow !  It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack Overflow. -Thank you

Comment: Thanks I also added  images so that it would better understand]

Answer (score 0):

How to make 3 html tables show exactly in excel file side by side. Currently the output is that the 3 tables are in the end of each other.  the code is above and the output is shown in the picture